# How to make the first view of a ConstraintLayout fits remaining space

Tags: android

So I have a constraint layout containing 3 text views.These 3 text views are aligned to the left so it gives this schema:

[Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmEUZ.png)
What I want is this:
Text views B and C should never ellipsize, only the text view A should if there is not enough space for these 3 to fit inside the constraint layout. Since it's the first view of the layout, how to achieve that ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. You should use `app:layout_constraintWidth_max="wrap"` and `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"` for text view A

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:padding="12dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_A"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tv_B"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_max="wrap"
        app:layout_goneMarginStart="0dp"
        tools:text="Very long long long long long long long long long text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_B"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tv_C"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv_A"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Text B" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_C"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv_B"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Text C" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you can give weight to them and they will limit their widths accordingly.
```

something like below but you have first create chain between them.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvOne"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="14dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lines="1"
        android:text="hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola hola "
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/tvTwo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTwo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/tvOne"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/tvThree"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvThree"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/tvTwo"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that TextView B and C are not sticked to the text view at their left side. I need everything to be aligned to the left without space between them